# Realm instances and multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading, realm

I'm trying to code something to get offline some content that could be watched later. This content is made of jsons, images, vidéos and pdfs :

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "id":"3b4c4f3da8bf9d1527010c5242e037b7",
      "type":"media"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "id":"58088318ef0b4832f6c0e70b",
  "content": "Hello World"
}
```

So basically my problem is that I switch between async network calls and realm db updates, and I can't figure out how to build it well.

I fist fetch the above Json must store it in realm, then I call a second route for each element to get `DetailedElement` and store it aswell. when an element contains a downloadable document I must dowload it and add its path as a member of `DetailedElement`. Thing is, I can't get my threads right.

I'd idealy like a method with this signature :

`FooBar.prefetch(Context ctx, String id, Callback cb)`

My first step should be to ensure it's launched in a non-UI Looper thread : I'm not sure how to do it

```
public static void Bar(final Context ctx, final String id) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            final Handler handler = new Handler();

            MainThingToDownload mainThingToDownload = realm.where(MainThingToDownload.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
            if (mainThingToDownload != null) {
                processMain(mainThingToDownload, realm, handler);
            } else {
                Api.getInstance().backendRepresentation.getMainThing(id).enqueue(new CustomRetrofitCallBack<>(null) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponseReceived(final MainThingToDownload mainThingToDownload) {

                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mainThingToDownload);
                                        processMain(mainThingToDownload, realm, handler);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Is it the right approach ? keeping the realm reference and the handler reference for its thread. And then I always do in my network callbacks something like that :

```
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    //... add downloaded object to realm or modifies one     
                }
            });     
        }
    });
```

I had lot of different errors with my code. Most of the time I don't use Realm on the thread where it should be used on and sometimes I use a realm instance that has already been closed.

Is this how I'm suppose to do it ? 
Thanks,

---

*What I did*

A `Program` contains a list of `Module`, each `Module` contains a list of `Element`.

**ProgramOfflineManager**

```
public class ProgramOfflineManager extends AbstractOfflineManager {

    private final static String TAG = "ModuleOfflineManager";

    public ProgramOfflineManager(Context ctx, String id, ErrorDisplayerInterface errorDisplayerInterface) {
        super(ctx, id, errorDisplayerInterface);
    }

    @Override
    protected void makeOffline() throws IOException {
        super.makeOffline();
        ProgramOfflineManager.makeOffline(id, ctx);
    }

    @Override
    protected void removeOffline() {
        super.removeOffline();
        ProgramOfflineManager.removeOffline(id, ctx);
    }

    public static void removeOffline(String programId, Context ctx) {

        Log.i(TAG, "to be deleted");
        Realm realm = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            //To be deleted
            final Program program = realm.where(Program.class).equalTo("id", programId).findFirst();
            Log.i("renaud", "courseDetailed matching is is not null : (detailed!=null)=>" + (program != null));
            if (program != null) {
                for (Module module : program.getModules()) {
                    CourseDetailed courseDetailed = realm.where(CourseDetailed.class).equalTo("id", module.getCourse()).equalTo("downloaded", true).findFirst();
                    if (courseDetailed != null) {
                        ModuleOfflineManager.removeOffline(module.getCourse(), ctx);
                    }
                }
                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        program.deleteFromRealm();
                        Log.i(TAG, "course has been deleted");
                    }
                });
            }
        } finally {
            if (realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
            realm = null;
        }
    }

    public static void makeOffline(final String programId, final Context ctx) throws IOException {
        Api.Service360Interface backend = Api.getInstance().backend;

        Response<Program> programResponse = backend.getProgram(programId).execute();

        if (programResponse.isSuccessful()) {
            final Program program = programResponse.body();

            Realm realm = null;
            try {
                realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        program.setDownloaded(true);
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(program);
                    }
                });

                for (final Module module : program.getModules()) {
                    long count = realm.where(CourseDetailed.class).equalTo("id", module.getCourse()).equalTo("downloaded", true).count();
                    if (count == 0) {
                        ModuleOfflineManager.makeOffline(module.getCourse(), ctx);
                    }
                }


            } finally {
                if (realm != null) {
                    realm.close();
                }
                realm = null;
            }
        }

    }


}
```

**ModuleOfflineManager**

```
public class ModuleOfflineManager extends AbstractOfflineManager {

    private final static String TAG = "ModuleOfflineManager";

    public ModuleOfflineManager(Context ctx, String id, ErrorDisplayerInterface errorDisplayerInterface) {
        super(ctx, id, errorDisplayerInterface);
    }

    @Override
    protected void makeOffline() throws IOException {
        super.makeOffline();
        ModuleOfflineManager.makeOffline(id, ctx);
    }

    @Override
    protected void removeOffline() {
        super.removeOffline();
        ModuleOfflineManager.removeOffline(id, ctx);
    }

    public static void removeOffline(String courseId, Context ctx) {

        Log.i(TAG, "to be deleted");
        Realm realm = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            //To be deleted
            final CourseDetailed detailed = realm.where(CourseDetailed.class).equalTo("id", courseId).findFirst();
            Log.i("renaud", "courseDetailed matching is is not null : (detailed!=null)=>" + (detailed != null));
            if (detailed != null) {
                for (Element element : detailed.getElements()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "next Element to suppress : " + element.getId());
                    final CourseElement courseElement = realm.where(CourseElement.class).equalTo("id", element.getId()).findFirst();
                    if (courseElement.getCollection() != null && courseElement.getCollection() == PostCollectionType.MEDIAS) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "it's a Media, erasing from db");
                        MediaDownloadUtils.eraseMedia(ctx, courseElement, realm);
                    }
                    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            courseElement.deleteFromRealm();
                            Log.i(TAG, "element has been deleted");
                        }
                    });

                }
                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        detailed.deleteFromRealm();
                        Log.i(TAG, "course has been deleted");
                    }
                });
            }
        } finally {
            if (realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
            realm = null;
        }
    }

    public static void makeOffline(final String courseId, final Context ctx) throws IOException {
        Api.Service360Interface backend = Api.getInstance().backend;

        Response<CourseDetailed> response = backend.getCourse(courseId).execute();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            final CourseDetailed courseDetailedResponse = response.body();

            Realm realm = null;
            try {
                realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        courseDetailedResponse.saveEnums();
                        courseDetailedResponse.setDownloaded(true);
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(courseDetailedResponse);
                    }
                });

                for (final Element element : courseDetailedResponse.getElements()) {

                    Call<CourseElement> call = Api.getInstance().getCourseElement(element.getCollection(), element.getId(), courseId);
                    Response<CourseElement> courseElementResponse = call.execute();
                    if (courseElementResponse.isSuccessful()) {
                        final CourseElement courseElement = courseElementResponse.body();
                        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                courseElement.setCourseElementType(CourseElementTypes.valueOf(element.getCollection()));
                                courseElement.saveEnums();
                                courseElement.setDownloaded(true);
                                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(courseElement);

                                MediaDownloadUtils.prefechMedia(ctx, courseElement);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (realm != null) {
                    realm.close();
                }
                realm = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AbstractOfflineManager**

```
public abstract class AbstractOfflineManager implements OfflineManagerInterface {

    private final static String TAG = "AbstractOfflineManager";

    final protected Context ctx;
    final protected String id;
    final protected ErrorDisplayerInterface errorDisplayerInterface;

    protected boolean status;

    public AbstractOfflineManager(Context ctx, String id, ErrorDisplayerInterface errorDisplayerInterface) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.id = id;
        this.errorDisplayerInterface = errorDisplayerInterface;
    }

    protected void makeOffline() throws IOException {
        //implementations in children
    }

    protected void removeOffline() {
        //implementations in children
    }

    @Override
    public CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener getClickListener() {
        return new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {

                Log.i(TAG, "clic ! isChecked : " + isChecked);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Looper.prepare();
                        status = isChecked;
                        if (isChecked) {
                            try {
                                makeOffline();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                errorDisplayerInterface.popError(null, e);
                            }
                        } else {
                            removeOffline();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        };
    } }
```

Now I'll create a `ElementOfflineManager`

Comment: Each thread must have it's own Realm instance. You should close it right after you are done with it, but not before.

Comment: For instance your onResponseReceived needs its own Realm instance, because it runs on a separate thread

Comment: That's why I use a handler, I think "Realm.getDefaultInstance()" is quite heavy, and that we should try to keep a reference to it and its thread. One operation like that results in dozens of async networks calls and as much db updates. I just would like to close it when everything is over.

Comment: Consider moving all logic after `toBeDeleted` into a single transaction, this currently is rather heavy on Realm - and you don't need `Looper.prepare()`.

Comment: Without Looper.prepare(), won't I have an exception ? I only need it to get live updates ? I don't think I can't move logic into a single transaction, because there is a ElementOfflineManager to be built that will deal with its own transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it the right approach ? keeping the realm reference and the handler reference for its thread.

Not necessary. Realm can be used on any background thread, as long as you close the instance.

Realm already manages handlers for the UI thread and its auto-updates, so you don't need to do that manually yourself.

---

You have extremely overcomplicated a rather simple problem. You should just make Retrofit execute synchronously on a background thread, rather than on the UI thread.

Like so:

```
protected ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

//...


public static void bar(final Context ctx, final String id) {
    MainThingToDownload mainThingToDownload = mRealm.where(MainThingToDownload.class)
                                                   .equalTo("id", id)
                                                   .findFirst(); 
                                       // assuming there is a UI thread Realm
    if (mainThingToDownload != null) {
        processMain(mainThingToDownload);
    } else {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Response<MainThingToDownload> response = Api.getInstance()
                                                            .backendRepresentation
                                                            .getMainThing(id)
                                                            .execute();
                MainThingToDownload mainThingToDownload = response.body();
                Realm realm = null;
                try {
                    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            realm.insertOrUpdate(mainThingToDownload);
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    if(realm != null) {
                        realm.close();
                    }
                }
            }
       });
}
```

---

---

For more general info, check out [the guide on the basics of Realm](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/basics-of-realm-a-guide-to-using-realm-1-2-0-634471c0fe8f#.j9vi1abnb), or [this very simple gist](https://gist.github.com/Zhuinden/e917936103c62146183fe770bdb9907d#file-realm-detail-view-example-java)

(here's the gist:

```
public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  // ...
  private RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<NewsPost>> realmChangeListener;
  private RealmResults<NewsPost> listenerSet;
  private long postId;

  private Realm realm;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    Injector.get().inject(this);
    postId = getIntent().getLongExtra("postId");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    realm = RealmManager.getRealm();

    realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<NewsPost>>() {
      @Override
      public void onChange(RealmResults<NewsPost> element) {
        NewsPost newsPost = realm.where(NewsPost.class)
                                    .equalTo(NewsPostFields.ID, postId)
                                    .findFirst();
        if(newsPost != null) { // if news post was downloaded on background thread, initalize view
          initView(newsPost);
        }
      }
    };
    listenerSet = realm.where(NewsPost.class)
                       .findAll();
    listenerSet.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener); // listen to changes in `NewsPost` table

    NewsPost newsPost = realm.where(NewsPost.class)
                                .equalTo(NewsPostFields.ID, postId)
                                .findFirst();
    if(newsPost == null) {
      // download news post if not available
      getNewsPostInteractor.getNewsPost(postId);
    } else {
      initView(newsPost);
    }
  }

  private void initView(NewsPost newsPost) {
    // set views
  }
}
```

)

---

Oh, and [you should close any Realm instance that you open with `getDefaultInstance()`](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149). I can see you aren't doing that.

Comment: Hello Mr EpicPandaForce, I'm refactoring to get something more like the code you helped me with earlier. Updating my Question

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best solution in this case - use functional reactive programming (rxJava library for android). By doing so, you can create trigger, emitting event every time your data is updated (by using PublishSubject) and handle concurrency easily. 
If you do so, avod using async.. methods, because synchronization will be done by redirecting event flow inside rx 'pipelines'.
Realm can't access objects from another thread if those objects were created from another thread, so, for multithreaded environment, allocate new realm instance, perform transaction and release instance. This is not mandatory, you can still use async method, but it will make interaction a bit more comprehensive.

Comment: I'll add RxJava later :). Don't wanna mix techs that I'm noob at.

Comment: As the rest of your comment, you're joining Tim Castelijns, I'll instanciate one realm instance in all my callbacks and see how it behaves.

Comment: introducing additional complexity with RxJava won't fix this

Comment: Actually, it will. It will help to avoid this callback tedium and will help with operation timing.

Comment: It won't because the main thread isn't immediately updated after a committed transaction on the background thread since 2.0.0. And he wouldn't have a callback hell if he didn't unnecessarily jump between threads, and just used `RealmChangeListener` as intended.